# Given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, find the range and domain of $fg(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We are given:

> $\eqalign{
>   & f(x) = x - 1  \cr 
>   & g(x) = {x^2} \cr} $

---

Given these functions the answer I get is:

$fg(x)=x^2-1$

As the range of $g(x)=x^2$ is always positive this means the domain of the new function is $x \geqslant 0 $
The range of this function is $fg(x) \geqslant  - 1$

However this is wrong, the answer in the textbook states that the domain is the set of real numbers, and I know this makes sense as it is a quadratic equation and can accept all values but doesn't the function $g(x)$ who's outputs form the inputs of the compound function $gf(x)$ limit the domain to being $x \geqslant 0 $ ?

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s true that the outputs of $g$ are non-negative, but since $f$ can accept any real number as input, it really doesn’t matter what the outputs of $g$ are. The domain of the composite function $f\circ g$ is the set of all acceptable inputs to $f\circ g$; $g$ can accept any real number as input, and the output of $g$ is always acceptable input to $f$, so $f\circ g$ can accept any real number as input. In other words, its domain really is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ah, I see! but say $g(x) = \sqrt x $, would I be right in thinking that would change things, as despite fg(x) being able to accept any real number the square root would restrict the domain to non-negative numbers, right?

Comment: @Assad: Yes, if $g$ were the square root function, then the domain of $f\circ g$ would indeed be the set of non-negative reals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing up the confusion Brian!

Comment: @Assad: You’re welcome!